# How could i set Delphi combobox current itemindex using IndexOfObject method with object info

Tags: delphi, combobox, indexof

I filled TStringList object as below:

```
var
infoObject: TStringObject;
dataObject: TStringList

_query.First;
for i := 0 to _query.RecordCount-1 do
begin
  infoObject := TStringObject.Create;
  infoObject.stringsData.Add(_query.Fields[0].AsString);
  dataObject.AddObject(_query.Fields[1].AsString, infoObject);

  _query.Next;
end;
```

and then use it to populate comboBox like this:

```
combo1.Items.Clear;
combo1.Items.AddStrings(dataObject);
```

Now I wat to set comboBox itemIndex with equal string value from DB. I know in routine scenario when I have text that show in comboBox az text use IndexOf will help me like this:

```
combo1.ItemIndex := combo1.Items.IndexOf('[text of item]');
```

but I want to set it with value exist in object and not Text. I see IndexOfObject method but it can't work as IndexOf or I don't know how should be use it.I write this lines but it not work:

```
itemObject := TStringObject.Create;
itemObject.stringsData.Add('[value of item]');
combo1.ItemIndex := combo1.Items.IndexOfObject(itemObject);
```

Can anyone help? Should mention I'm using Delphi 2007 and Raize Componenet ComboBox.

Comment: The second instance of `itemObject` (created in your last code block) will not exist in the Objects. The first one (created in the loop in your first code block) will have a different memory address, and therefore the `IndexOfObject` will return -1. It appears you're trying to locate one that matches a specific text value, but I'm not certain if that's the case.

Comment: @KenWhite You Improve my perception, Thanks dud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not storing any object pointerss in the ComboBox itself, so you cannot use the ComboBox's own `IndexOfObject()` method.  Not that it would work anyway, because `IndexOfObject()` searches for an object pointer, but you are looking for text instead.  You will have to iterate the `TStringList` looking for the object text manually, eg:

```
var
  dataObject: TStringList;

function IndexOfObjectText(const S: String): Integer;
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  for I := 0 to dataObject.Count-1 do
  begin
    if TStringObject(dataObject.Objects[I]).stringData.IndexOf(S) <> -1 then
    begin
      Result := I;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
combo1.ItemIndex := IndexOfObjectText('[value of item]');
```

Comment: That is right and worked for me. Appreciate and I go to use it. I'll accept this as answer but please advise me about using IndexOfObject() to find item with object pointer as you mentioned if that is rare scenario. Thanks again.

Comment: It does not make sense to bother with `IndexOfObject()` since you are not storing object pointers anywhere that you can retrieve from to then look for them in one of your lists.